# Alert messages are blocked in windows 8 metro IE 10 in popups

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, internet-explorer-10

I have a page that shows an alert message. In windows 8 metro IE browser(Not the desktop browser), shows the alert message as expected. But when i open that page as a popup, alert messages are not firing. But these things are working fine in other browsers including windows 8 IE 10 desktop browser.

does anyone know to handle this?